# How to change username on arqade's mobile interface

Tags: support

How can I change my username on arqade's mobile interface? I have seen tutorials for the non-mobile interface, but I just can't seem to find the **edit** button for the mobile interface. Help!

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]